# Problem with Polymorphic Relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a way to get the details of a person depending on the group it belongs to.
My database looks like this:
**persons**:

| id | group | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person | 9 |
| 2 | company | 30 |
| 3 | person | 9 |

and so on.

Each "group" has a model which contains detail information for this record specific to the group.

For example:

**persondetails** looks like this

| id | person_id | firstname | lastname | birthname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Harry | Example | Bornas |
| 2 | 3 | Henrietta | Example | Bornas |

I created models for each table and I'm no trying to implement a relationship which allows me to query a person->with('details') via the person model (for example: for a complete list of all persons no matter which type it is).
For single records I got it working via a simple "if $this->group === person {$this->hasOne()}" relation, which doesn't work for listings.

I tried to wrap my head around a way to use a polymorphic relationship, so I put the following into the person model:

```
 public function details(){
        Relation::morphMap([
            'person' => 'App\Models\Persondetail',
            'company' => 'App\Models\Companydetail',
        ]);
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

and a subsequent

```
public function person(){
        return $this->morphMany(Person::class, 'details');
    }
```

which doesn't work sadly. Where is my thinking error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the reply by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8158202/akhzar-javed I figure it out, but I had to change the code a bit:

Instead of the code in the answer, I had to use the following:

```
     public function details()
        {
            Relation::morphMap([
                'person' => 'App\Models\Persondetails',
                'company' => 'App\Models\Companydetail',
            ]);
            return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'group', 'id', 'person_id');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using laravel convention for the keys, you need to define the keys on your relation

```php
public function details()
{
    Relation::morphMap([
         'person' => 'App\Models\Persondetail',
         'company' => 'App\Models\Companydetail',
    ]);
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'group', 'type');
}
```

Docs Link:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#morph-one-to-one-key-conventions

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it good enough or my english isn't the best anymore after 8hours of working:

person_id in - for example Persondetails - is the FK to the PK "id" in Persons.
So basically I want to get the details to the person based on the group which matches the person_id in the *details Model.